# useState() react/electron ends up in blank screen

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-forge

I am writing a react-electron program. In an attempt to use modals from react-bootstrap module [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-live). I've stumbled across a problem and after some testing figured out that it was the useState() line that was causing the issue. Whenever I include useState() the screen goes completely blank, not just the component that was using the state but the entire window of the electron app with all the parent and sibling components as well. This is not tied to using it for the modal most likely as it doesn't work with simple useState() cases either. Here is my code for this component:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { Component, useState } from 'react';

import {Character} from '../../../../Data/Character';
import StatusBar from '../../../Components/StatusBar';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
export interface HealthCardProps {
    Naomi:Character
}
 
export interface HealthCardState {
    
}
 
class HealthCard extends React.Component<HealthCardProps, HealthCardState> {

    GetLabelHealth(){
        let label:string = this.props.Naomi.currentHealth+"/"+this.props.Naomi.maxHealth;
        return label;
    };
    GetLabelHitDice(currentHD:number,HD:number){
        let label:string = currentHD + "d"+HD
        return label
    }
    
    render() { 
        const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

        const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
        const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
      

  return (
      
    <>
        <div className="card" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
        <span style={{fontSize:"20px",color:"#708F93"}}>Hit Points</span>
        <div className="HealthBar">
            <StatusBar bColor="#9DBE9E"
                       fColor="#BAE6BC"
                       value={(this.props.Naomi.currentHealth/this.props.Naomi.maxHealth)*100}
                       label={this.GetLabelHealth()}/>
             {this.props.Naomi.classes.length>=0 && 
                this.props.Naomi.classes.map((c)=>
                <div style={{marginTop:"2px"}}>
                <StatusBar bColor="#c5d2db"
                       fColor="#D8E2E9"
                       value={(c.currentHDie/c.classLevel)*100}
                       label={this.GetLabelHitDice(c.currentHDie,c.hitDie)}/>
                       </div>
                )}
                <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
        </div>
    </div>
    </> );
    }
}
 
export default HealthCard;
```

I'd appreciate any help, I'm new to electron and react in general.

Comment: I don'y know anything about electron, but in `react` you only use hooks `useState` with functional components, check react docs on hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update I solved my problem, partly thanks to mu-majid in the comments. Here is the updated code in case anyone is starting out and stumbles across this.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component, useState } from 'react';

import {Character} from '../../../../Data/Character';
import StatusBar from '../../../Components/StatusBar';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
export interface HealthCardProps {
    Naomi:Character
}
 
export interface HealthCardState {
    
}
 
class HealthCard extends React.Component<HealthCardProps, HealthCardState> {
    state = {
        isOpen: false
      };

      openModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: true });
      closeModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });

    GetLabelHealth(){
        let label:string = this.props.Naomi.currentHealth+"/"+this.props.Naomi.maxHealth;
        return label;
    };
    GetLabelHitDice(currentHD:number,HD:number){
        let label:string = currentHD + "d"+HD
        return label
    }
     Example() {
        const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
      
        const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
        const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
      
        return (
          <>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
              Launch demo modal
            </Button>
      
            
          </>
        );
      }
    
    render() { 
      

  return (
      
    <>
        <div className="card" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
        <span style={{fontSize:"20px",color:"#708F93"}}>Hit Points</span>
        <div className="HealthBar" onClick={this.openModal}>
            <StatusBar bColor="#9DBE9E"
                       fColor="#BAE6BC"
                       value={(this.props.Naomi.currentHealth/this.props.Naomi.maxHealth)*100}
                       label={this.GetLabelHealth()}/>
             {this.props.Naomi.classes.length>=0 && 
                this.props.Naomi.classes.map((c)=>
                <div style={{marginTop:"2px"}}>
                <StatusBar bColor="#c5d2db"
                       fColor="#D8E2E9"
                       value={(c.currentHDie/c.classLevel)*100}
                       label={this.GetLabelHitDice(c.currentHDie,c.hitDie)}/>
                       </div>
                )}
                
        </div>
    </div>
    <Modal show={this.state.isOpen} onHide={this.closeModal}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.closeModal}>
                  Close
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.closeModal}>
                  Save Changes
                </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
    </> );
    }
}
 
export default HealthCard;
```